# Generate resource task failed error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

From what I've seen about this error they are all slightly different

prior to today my code worked fine. (Visual studio 2015)

the error that I am getting is shown below

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      The
>   "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResGenDependencies.GetResXFileInfo(String
>   resxFile)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.ShouldRebuildResgenOutputFile(String
>   sourceFilePath, String outputFilePath)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.GetResourcesToProcess(List`1&
>   inputsToProcess, List`1& outputsToProcess, List`1& cachedOutputFiles) 
>   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Progress_Tracker

I have no idea what this is and no solution I have seen so far has helped me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the code that is causing the error?

Comment: There is no code related to this @Arcans, it is an internal error in the compiler caused by some cleanup event. See the link in my answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman ohh intressting, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be [a known bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/364) in the RTM of Visual Studio 2015 (or better said in the MSBuild tool which Visual Studio uses).

The temporary solution seems to be this:

> To work around #314, completely delete all build outputs and build again--the issue is that an internal cache gets interpreted incorrectly on the old bits, causing this crash.

So delete the `bin` and `obj` folder from your project and try again.

The fix seems to be deployed in [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx). If you haven't installed that yet, I would give that a try.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you so much!